# Disable input fields but do not block the user from selecting the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I know we can use the 'disabled' attribute to accomplish  what I'm asking, but, since for this project I'm working on we are using the 'old' edge (webview 1), where if you disable an input field, the user can no longer select the text (with horizontal scrolling effect using the mouse), and they can only select the text using crtl+A. Now, at the moment some of our input fields are readonly which works fine, however, in the old edge, since the input field is not disabled, when you tab out within the website, the focus is still going to those readonly fields and even the text gets highlighted and we do not need that. I have tried using the 'disabled' attribute and it works like a charm, but I can no longer scroll select the text for some reason and I can only do ctrl+A. Is there a way I can accomplish disabling an input field but making sure I can still copy its content using any browser (webview1,....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just disable tabbing into those fields with

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" name="myfield" readonly>
```

?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the tabindex=-1 but old edge doesn't recognize it

Comment: What about disabling tabbing into those fields with some JavaScript? That's a workaround for such cases

Comment: I can try that, do you have any snippet code suggestion? (please do not provide jquery)